# Simple percentage question

Tags: percentages

Simple % question, if x individual has committed to 6 hours of work (100%), then 25 hours is added, in terms of % how much has been added?

I currently work it out like this:

25/6 * 100 = 416%

Meaning they have committed to an additional 316% of work - is this correct? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $416$% you found out is the additional % of work they have committed. Total would come out to be $416+100=516$%
This can also be verified as total hours now are $31$, hence the $%$ would come out to be $\frac{31*100}{6}=516$%
So the $416$% you found out is additional.